# Is the appropriate way to fetch user roles/permissions/information from an ID Token or an API endpoint (or other)?

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-page-application, access-token

When creating an Angular web application that also has a backend API, I feel like there are a few different options when it comes to getting User Info such as roles/permissions/display name/email/etc.

1. We can use an ID Token to store user claims like this. That token can be put into local storage or a cookie and the Angular app can read it and render the UI/guard against unauthorized route navigation/etc as soon as the app spins up (since the ID token is available right then and there).
2. We can NOT use an ID Token for this information at all and instead have an API endpoint that we have to call every page re-load to fetch this data. The server would decode our access token/ID token and return the data in JSON format.
3. Lastly, there could be some hybrid solution where basic User Info like names/emails are stored int he ID token and available right away, but user permissions (which could be a larger payload and maybe not wanted in a token that should be small) could be fetched via an API

Is there maybe a 4th option I didn't think about?

I haven't been able to find many conventions around which of these options is the best. I like the ID token option as it requires no "blocking" of the UI until the API request is done making the page load that much faster, but I'm not sure if that goes against other conventions.

Answer (score 1):

All your approaches rely on a permissions-based system where you would have been granted permissions upon login. These are sometimes referred to as birth rights since they are typically given when the user is created or whenever their permission sets change. The typical way to carry birth rights around is to have them as scopes / assertions inside an identity token (e.g. OAUth 2.0) that you pass along from service to service.

You can also have your applications retrieve additional permissions / roles / entitlements from a backend store (a database for instance) based on the user ID so that you know what your user can or cannot do.

So far this is essentially role-based access control / permissions-based access control.

The main challenge with that approach is role explosion / permissions explosion as well as token bloat (too many permissions in the token) and administration pains - you have to assign roles and permissions to users all the time. You have to deprovision. It becomes a management nightmare and a risk you may have the wrong permissions set for users. You then need to think about identity and access governance as well as recertification. Heavy.

### What's the alternative?

You definitely need some roles - yes - but they should be kept to a minimum - essentially the business roles you need in your apps e.g. a doctor, a nurse, a non-medical staff rather than doctor_hospital1_unitA.

You should then express your authorization as plain-old English policies using any number of attributes - not just user attributes but also contextual information (time, location), resource information (what type of object, who owns it, where is it? How sensitive is it?), and action information (view, edit, delete...).

[image: The multiple dimensions of attribute-based access control]

#### Sample Policies

- A doctor can view a medical record if they are assigned to the patient the medical record belongs to
- A nurse can view a medical record if the medical record is in the same unit as the nurse
- A non-medical staff can view the financial section of a medical record but not the medical section.

#### Attribute-Based Access Control

Following this approach is called attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)). In ABAC, you clearly decouple your app from the authorization process. Authorization is expressed as policies rather than code which makes it easier to:

- update
- audit
- review

#### How to implement?

You have several options to implement ABAC (from open-source to commercial). You can go down the XACML ([xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml)) path, the [ALFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML)) [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa) path, or others. They all have similar architectures with:

- the notion of a policy decision point (PDP): a service that evaluates the authorization requests against the set of policies you defined and produce decisions (Permit / Deny) that can be enriched with additional information e.g. order to do two-factor Authentication.
- the notion of a policy enforcement point (PEP): an interceptor that sits in front of or inside your API that will send an authorization request to the PDP.

I've written about the architecture more in detail in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49733063/1021725).

#### ALFA Example

In ALFA, a sample policy would look like:

```
policyset viewMedicalRecord{
    target clause object == "medical record" and action == "view"
    apply firstApplicable
    policy allowDoctors{
        target clause role == "doctor"
        apply firstApplicable
        rule allowAssignedPatient{
            permit
            condition patient.assignedDoctor == user.name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These are all concepts that are completely new to me, so please give me time to read up on your other post.  It appears like my question was less trivial than originally thought. Thank you for your in-depth answer!

Comment: Feel free to ping me